# Slick2D Collision Detection

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I was wondering if there are any other ways to do collision detection using the slick2D libraries, other than the standard co-ordinates way (if (xpos < 3 && ypos > 8)) etc.

Comment: I'd suggest reading into AABB Collison strategies, or for more complex purposes, separating axis theorem (SAT). There are no entity Collison detection methods built into slick.

Answer (score 2):

*Note: I do realize that this question is a bit old, yet this answer might help future visitors*

**Yes, there are.**

In Slick2D you can check for collisions between shapes with the Shape#intersects(Shape other) method.

The Shape class already provides a lot of useful methods, but I suggest using the Rectangle class which is probably simpler to use for a simple game, as you do not have to care about Polygon transformations. Yet, if you wish to have more complex shapes you should use the Polygon class. You will have to take care of some things yourself, so I recommend creating a Hitbox class extending the Polygon class, but with the Polygon approach you will be more flexible and you will be able to rotate your shapes (which is not possibly with the Rectangle class).

**Resources**

- http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/geom/Shape.html
- http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/geom/Shape.html#intersects(org.newdawn.slick.geom.Shape
- http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/geom/Polygon.html
- http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/geom/Rectangle.html